# Using a temp file for lookups?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lookup

I have a C# program that is executed on an EC2 cloud server and connecting to an RDS SQL DB. It collects some data, checks if that data exists an SQL DB table and if not it adds the item to a list to be bulk saved later. Now I'm struggling a bit on what the best approach is here.

I've tried these options so far:
a) before inserting make a DB make a call to see if it exists. 
Pro: less memory intensive. Can run on cheaper cloud servers. 
Cons: higher DB reads. Slower performance 
b) Put a Unique Constraint on the tables and in code catch this Unique Constraint exception and move on. 
Pro: less memory intensive. Can run on cheaper cloud servers. 
Cons: higher DB reads. MUCH Slower performance. Id increment of the transaction don't get rolled back leading to an error down the road of making out the int Id column
c) At the start, make a bulk SQL call for all the lookup values and put them all into a hashed set. Reference this hashed set to see if the value exists or not. 
Pro: Much much faster. Much less DB reads
Cons: Pay more for servers with more memory. Risk hitting Out of memory errors as it scales.

The reason I say making single SQL calls is slow is because of the latency of the RDS DB. It's minor but adds up when doing 100k calls in a row to see if something exists. Ideally I'd like as fast performance as possible. I've considered using DyanmoDb but the pricing is just too much and doesn't make much sense in my situation.

So is there some way to save lookups to a file on the local disk that can be quickly referenced later? 
please tell me what it is!

Comment: Have you looked at memcache or equivalent?

Comment: Does memcache use less memory than say a hashed set?

Comment: I don't see any downvotes but... this is really an opinion question with no right answer. Lots of ways to deal with database writes, caching, etc.

Comment: @user2326106 No, memcache will use more memory than a simple hashed set or equivalent in-memory data structure. The advantage is that memcache (or equivalent) is a general purpose key/value cache that can be run on a separate server if needed so can scale better and can be accessed from multiple clients. That may be overkill in your case, if your needs are simple and your cache footprint is relatively small.

Comment: gotcha. Interesting, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

One quick option you could try is to write a stored procedure that accepts the insert data, then the sp would check for the record, and if not found add it, or return an error.

Doesn't cut down on the reads or writes, but does cut down on the roundtrips to the server, and you did say the latency is a problem.

Another option is to use a temp table and do inserts into it without checks (fast), and then do a "insert into mastertable select * from temptable where record is not in mastertable' type of query to insert rows as a batch - the usefulness of this option will depend on whether or not you can bunch up a bunch of rows to insert at once.